# Managed Social Account none to select

Tags: service, social-customer-service

I am getting Post to create a Case in Service cloud, However when I try to reply to the Facebook Messenger Message I get drop down to select a social account and there is none to select. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can reply to a Social Account you need to enable the Social Account. This is done my first going to the profile for that user.

- This is done by going to Setup in the quick find box on the left type
  in Profile.
- Edit the profile of the user.
- On the top of the profile click on "Enabled Social Account Access"
- Click on Edit button and Select the Social Account you want that
  profile to access.
  After the is done the user will be able to select the user account in the post. 
  [image]